# Rust + LLVM ORC JIT cannot find symbol address

Tags: rust, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I have been trying to use the ORC JIT compiler from the LLVM C bindings in Rust, but I keep running into the problem that `LLVMOrcGetSymbolAddress` is not able to find the symbol of my function `run` in the module I provide it. The code below combines the most important parts of my code that unfortunately doesn't work. All goes well until the last part of `foo`, where an error is returned because the function cannot be found. The function is definitely in the module, as `LLVMGetNamedFunction` is able to find it, but somehow the ORC engine cannot see it. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I am using LLVM 6.0 and the `llvm-sys` Rust bindings. Everything works fine if I use MCJIT but I need ORC for lazy compilation.

```
fn foo(module: LLVMModuleRef) -> Result<I64Func, LlvmError> {
    let def_triple = LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple();
    let mut target_ref = ptr::null_mut();
    let mut error_str = ptr::null_mut();

    // Get target from default triple
    if LLVMGetTargetFromTriple(def_triple, &mut target_ref, &mut error_str) != 0 {
        let msg = format!("Creating target from triple failed: {}", CStr::from_ptr(error_str).to_str().unwrap());
        LLVMDisposeMessage(def_triple);
        LLVMDisposeMessage(error_str);
        return Err(LlvmError(msg));
    }

    // Check if JIT is available
    if LLVMTargetHasJIT(target_ref) == 0 {
        let msg = format!("Cannot do JIT on this platform");
        LLVMDisposeMessage(def_triple);
        return Err(LlvmError(msg));
    }

    // Create target machine
    let tm_ref = LLVMCreateTargetMachine(target_ref, 
                                         def_triple,
                                         CString::new("").unwrap().as_ptr(), 
                                         CString::new("").unwrap().as_ptr(),
                                         llvm_opt_level(optimization_level)?,
                                         LLVMRelocMode::LLVMRelocDefault,
                                         LLVMCodeModel::LLVMCodeModelJITDefault);
    LLVMDisposeMessage(def_triple);
    let engine = LLVMOrcCreateInstance(tm_ref);

    // Add eagerly compiled IR
    let mut handle = LLVMOrcModuleHandle::default();
    let shared_module = LLVMOrcMakeSharedModule(module);
    let ctx = engine as *mut libc::c_void;
    map_orc_err(engine, LLVMOrcAddEagerlyCompiledIR(engine, 
                                                    &mut handle, 
                                                    shared_module, 
                                                    symbol_resolver_callback, 
                                                    ctx))?;

    // Find function named 'run'
    let c_name = CString::new("run").unwrap().as_ptr();
    let mut func_addr = LLVMOrcTargetAddress::default();
    map_orc_err(engine, LLVMOrcGetSymbolAddress(engine, &mut func_addr, c_name))?;
    if func_addr == 0 {
        // This errors always gets thrown
        return Err(LlvmError(format!("No function named {} in module", name)));
    }
    let function: I64Func = mem::transmute(func_addr);

    Ok(function)
}

extern "C" fn symbol_resolver_callback(symbol: *const libc::c_char, ctx: *mut libc::c_void) -> LLVMOrcTargetAddress {
    let mut address = LLVMOrcTargetAddress::default();
    let engine: LLVMOrcJITStackRef = ctx as LLVMOrcJITStackRef;

    unsafe { LLVMOrcGetSymbolAddress(engine, &mut address, symbol) };

    address
}

unsafe fn map_orc_err(engine: LLVMOrcJITStackRef, error_code: LLVMOrcErrorCode) -> Result<(), LlvmError> {
    match error_code {
        LLVMOrcErrorCode::LLVMOrcErrSuccess => Ok(()),
        LLVMOrcErrorCode::LLVMOrcErrGeneric => {
            let c_str: &CStr = CStr::from_ptr(LLVMOrcGetErrorMsg(engine));
            let str_slice: &str = c_str.to_str().unwrap();
            let str_buf: String = str_slice.to_owned();
            Err(LlvmError(str_buf))
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I tried downgrading to LLVM 4.0 just to see what effect that might have. I still cannot resolve the function, but now I'm getting an assertion error:

```
Assertion failed: (!Name.empty() && "getNameWithPrefix requires non-empty name"), function getNameWithPrefixImpl, file /tmp/llvm-4.0-20180412-49671-1pw0nxu/llvm-4.0.1.src/lib/IR/Mangler.cpp, line 37.
```

EDIT 2: Below is some basic IR for which the engine fails to find the function address:

```
define i64 @bar(i64 %arg) {
    %1 = add i64 %arg, 1
    ret i64 %1
}

define i64 @run(i64 %arg) {
    %1 = add i64 %arg, 1
    %2 = call i64 @bar(i64 %1)
    ret i64 %2
}
```

Comment: AFAIK LLVMOrcGetSymbolAddress only looks at exported symbols (in the C++ API this is optional). Are there any suspicious function attributes? Also this may fail on Windows, because there is (or was) a bug in the flag translation, but I guess by your file names that you are not using it.

Comment: This is what the run function looks like in IR (after optimization):

    define i64 @run(i64 %r.input) local_unnamed_addr {
    
    }

I'm not using Windows indeed, I'm on MacOS. What does looking only at exporting symbols imply? I'm sorry, I'm kind of new at compilers. I based my code on what I found in the unit tests of LLVM (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/unittests/ExecutionEngine/Orc/OrcCAPITest.cpp), which seems to be doing mostly the same thing.

Comment: In C a `static` function would not be exported (to other translation units). AFAIK the decision in the JIT is made using OS-specific attributes. I just had similar problems related to this, yours may well be unrelated. If you have the time to build LLVM from source you could most easily check this by editing LLVMOrcGetSymbolAddress to pass `false` as last parameter to findSymbolAddress

Comment: Thanks, I will try building it from source and see what happens. Out of curiosity, do you remember what fixed it for you in the end?

Comment: On Windows, the underlying LLVM bug was not fixed at the time and we had to make it expose non-exported symbols which was no problem for our usecase and easy with the C++ API. On MacOS and Linux, JIT is much better supported, so an LLVM bug seems less likely. Should your program work with the modified findSymbol, you can extend your question with some IR, and try to find out why the symbol was not exported.

Comment: Unfortunately modifying the `findSymbol` call did not work, still getting the same assert error. I'm not sure if this information helps, but using MCJIT and `LLVMGetFunctionAddress` worked without a problem, but I need ORC so that I generate code/compile on the fly.